# if possible Password validation can make as a model class?

Tags: ios

If i send the UITextfield Text as a parameter to one method that method should test all these conditions and return a BOOL value
either true or false. This is my code, how to use Model class in below code?please help me.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {



    if(string.length == 0){
        // Returning yes here to allow entry of backspace
        return YES;
    }

    if([string isEqualToString:@" "]){
        // Returning no here to restrict whitespace
        return NO;
    }


    if([passwrd.text length] <= 8)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;

   }

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //int numberofCharacters = 0;

    BOOL lowerCaseLetter = 0,upperCaseLetter = 0,digit = 0,specialCharacter = 0;
    if([passwrd.text length] >= 8)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < [passwrd.text length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [passwrd.text characterAtIndex:i];
            if(!lowerCaseLetter)
            {
                lowerCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
            }
            if(!upperCaseLetter)
            {
                upperCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
            }
            if(!digit)
            {
                digit = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
            }
            if (!specialCharacter && [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c]) {
                specialCharacter = YES;
            }
        }
        if(specialCharacter && digit && lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
            message:@"Successfully Created Password"
            delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
            message:@"Please Ensure that you have at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character"
            delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
        message:@"Please Enter your Valid Password "
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [passwrd resignFirstResponder];
    passwrd.text=@"";
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Something is definitely missing in your question. What is Model class?

Comment: Is this code write on NSObject class. any examples,please help me

Comment: Its working perfectly. but how to use model class(NSObject class) on above code.

Comment: what goal you're trying to achieve? why do you need NSObject?

Comment: if i send the textfield text as a parameter to one method that method should test all these conditions and return a bool value
either true or false